# Completely Web based bastion/jump host for SSH/HTTPs

Tags: linux, web-apps, remote-access

I've been trying a lot of various web based remote access services and I have not found one that meets my needs.

I have tried the following software and each kinda meets parts of my needs, but I would like to find an all-in-one solution. I have listed the issues with each below each bullet point.

- Apache Guacamole

  - This one is almost 100% what I need, but does not have "reverse proxy" functionality, i.e. the ability to open upstream web GUIs in the web app itself.
- Gravitational Teleport

  - This one has web app functionality, but requires a Certificate authority or agent to use SSH. Neither of which I have or intend to have ever.
- Meshcentral

  - Despite the old-looking interface, it doesn't actually allow SSH in a browser (without agent), and apparently requires port forwarding. Additionally, the upstream web access doesn't appear to allow different ports, which is a deal breaker.
- DIY solution

  - My temporary solution that is not great, I used a link dashboard (homer) to "publish" links to upstream servers and then reverse proxy them with NGINX. I also then slapped Guacamole along side it for SSH/VNC access. Hard to manage, and not very easy to use (especially for a large number of hosts).

Requirements:

- Completely self hosted (on linux)
- Access to servers via SSH (username/password and public key auth)
- Access to services via HTTP/HTTPs (ability to change endpoint port)
- Agentless - no extra software required on either the client or the server
- Web Based - all SSH and other Web GUIs are accessible from a clients browser. No agents (client, bastion or server) and no port forwarding.

Nice-to-haves:

- RDP/VNC
- 2FA (Personally I use Authy, so support for that is nice)
- Open source
- Session recording/logging

It seems near impossible to find a solution that actually does bastion/jump host entirely in the browser. All the functionality I need appears in different software in different ways, so all I need is to find a piece of software that has all the features I need.

Hopefully someone knows of something that fits.